# Database standardization for matching rules

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have an application that has Projects, and under each of these projects there can be a number of tasks depending on the specifics of the project's setup (and sometimes the same task multiple times). Tasks can be created based on settings of the project itself or by related requirements on other tables (IE: whether there is an associated file that expected for the project on the Project_Files table). A list of tasks for the project are derived from the Tasks table and added to the Project_Tasks table, along with the ID for the Project (And a unique additional key in the event that there are multiple versions of the same task).

Formerly this was all handled by the desktop application.  When a new project was created in the project, a function was run that checked for and added lines to the Project_Tasks table.  The problem is that

1. We are trying to transition this application from a winforms application to an MVC
2. this method produced inconsistencies in terms of tasks being added properly.

I'm trying to determine the best way of creating the lines in the Project_Tasks table, but the only way I can picture to do it in the tables is to create a corresponding field for every field in the Projects table in the Tasks Table and then do a join statement.  It seems like this is a lot of work if I ever need to add tasks to the Task table or fields to the Projects table. Is there an easier way than this?

Comment: "MVC 2"? Ancient history. Any reason for this choice of obsolete version? Anyway if you have a problem with some code, please show it. It's not obvious from your description why changing from desktop to web would affect a script which creates rows in a database table, unless you're supplying the wrong data somehow. And for that we'd need to see some code which relates to that process.

Comment: MVC 2 was just a byproduct of formatting.  I've corrected.